# Resharper for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any plugin for eclipse similar to resharper for vs ?

Comment: No, but you can buy IntelliJ.

Comment: What functionality of Resharper are you missing in Eclipse?

Comment: @Jesper Find all usages. Is there list of all shortcuts for eclipse.

Comment: @Damir, hitting Ctrl+Shift+L in Eclipse will give you the list of all shortcuts in Eclipse. Ctrl+Shift+G might actually help you - it gives you the list of all references in the current workspace.

Comment: @duffymo, IntelliJ CE is free and has most of the refactoring that the full version has.

Comment: Yes I know, but I think IntelliJ is far more than the factoring stuff.  I pay for the Ultimate edition because it's worth it.  ReSharper is paid software, too.  It has far more than the refactorings.  I think the Ultimate to ReSharper analogy is the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In December 2010 it was like this: Eclipse Java IDE (JDT) has build in support for refactoring, so you don't need an extra tool like for Visual Studio.

*At the time of writing this answer December 2010, Resharper does not have had more features than Eclipse, but it maybe changed since this.*

Comment: Are you saying that Visual Studio wasn't built in support for refactoring?

Comment: @italii Korsakov: this answer is 2 years old, and yes in this time the VS Refactoring support without extra tools (lets say) was quite restricted

Comment: All basic level of refactoring is available out of box with Visual Studio... extra tools provide advance features...

Comment: -1, ReSharper has hundreds of features besides simple refactoring.

Comment: @Davor: fist of all his answer is more then 3 1/2 years old, and was true in time of writing. Second: Please name some of the "hundred of features beside simple refactoring" that are not build in in JDT, to make our comment a good one.

Comment: @Hmm, read that Dec 13 as Dec 2013. Anyway, you can see the feature list on their site: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/. There's a lot more than renames and extractions there. I use it mostly for code analysis.

Comment: @Davor Dec 13 '10 is 13 of December 2010; thanks for the list, but I found no features that is not in eclipse (JDT) except "Value Tracking"

Comment: Eclipse's support for refactoring is somewhat limited, in my opinion.

Comment: Eclipse is VERY limited in refactoring in comparison to the far superior Visual Studio.

Comment: Resharper has plenty of refactoring and navigation tools. Resharper just makes it easier and even faster. This answer is marked. But imo it onlt confuses those with a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin to give you IntelliJ IDEA keyboard shortcuts, but Eclipse supports most of the refactorings that ReSharper (and IDEA) do.

I can not remember the name of the plugin, but I have used it before.

If you like resharper maybe you should take a look at IntelliJ IDEA.