# Does eclipse have a free Java refactoring plugin that can extract a class including both fields and methods?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, refactoring

This refactoring example is available in IntelliJ IDEA so based on the questions:

[Java refactoring tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708164/java-refactoring-tools)

[A tool like ReSharper, but for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615334/a-tool-like-resharper-but-for-java)

I suspect the answer to my question is no, but I'm hoping things might have changed since these questions were asked?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428113/resharper-for-eclipse - quite fresh discussing ;)

Comment: You might have better luck if you ask a more specific questions. Eclipse has very good refactoring support. You are going to need to define what specifically you are looking on top of that. If you assume that everyone is familiar with IntelliJ IDEA you are limiting the pool of people who can help you.

Comment: For example, eclipse can extract a class, but it only extracts fields, not methods...  I've changed the title and description to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Others have suggested this feature to Eclipse (See https://bugs.eclipse.org/312347), but, it hasn't been implemented yet.